# same validation on multiple servlets in one application

Tags: java, servlets

How to implement some logic for example Validation which is common for all servlets without writing it in all servlets? As Servlets are already extending from an abstract class we can not create a parent Servlet and extend that in child servlets. Then How can I achieve similar functionality? If the answer is some filter / interceptor / framework then can we do it without using any framework?

Comment: server side validation ?

Comment: @Amrola - yes. Is it possible to do from client side? If yes then how?

Comment: tell me what you want to do this validation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use servlet filters. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html for details.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can use? or this is best approach?

Answer (score 1):

@vaishali33 : you can use Filter in the following way:

```
public class ServletFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(validate(request)){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else{
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/error").include(request, response);
        }
    }

    private boolean validate(ServletRequest request){
        // here you can get the parameter from request and put your validation logic and return boolean accordingly
        return true;  // sample
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

And in the web.xml file, add the following lines of code:

```
<web-app>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CommonValidator</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CommonValidator</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve reutilization through aggregation also. I.e. you could develop a Singleton utility class with your validations and include a reference to it on every Servlet. It'll probably be easier to develop and test than filters.

Answer (score 0):

`Servlet filters` should do the trick with little effort.

You also might want to use `AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). It comes usually with`Spring Framework` along. Thus you can apply you validation not only to servlets, but also to other artifacts of your app.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like the following :

```
public class GeneralServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public boolean validate() {

    }

}


public class MyServlet extends GeneralServlet {


}
```

this what i used to do in my previous work .

and please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: This one seems to be good idea if one does not want to use Filters or any other framework. Thanks!